# How to handle 3rd party Camera apps on ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE in Android?

Tags: android, camera

I'm starting a `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent to start camera caption.

```
pictureActionIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (pictureActionIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (photoFile != null) {
        pictureActionIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
    }
}
startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

If the default camera application is used, there is no problem.
But how can I handle the intent if a 3rd party camera application is selected in the picker dialog?

If I'm using for example the CandyCamera nothing happens.
Usually tha captured Images will be shown in a `ImageView`. If CandyCamera is selected and a picture is taken, nothing happens.

Example:

```
switch (requestCode) {
        case CAMERA_REQUEST:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                galleryAddPic();
                setPic();

                break;
            }
```

The `createImageFile()` that is used in `photoFile = createImageFile();`:

```
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    String uuid = items.get("uuid");

    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            uuid, //prefix
            ".jpg",        //suffix
            storageDir     //directory
    );


    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

And this is the setPic():

```
private void setPic() {

int targetW = 150;
int targetH = 150;

// Get the dimensions of the bitmap
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
try {
    InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath));
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, bmOptions);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.d("In setPic:", " konnte Datei nicht finden.");
}

//BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

// Determine how much to scale down the image
int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);

// Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;
Bitmap bitmap = null;

try {
    InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath));
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, bmOptions);
    saveImageInXML saveImageInXML = new saveImageInXML();
    saveImageInXML.execute();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.d("In setPic:", " konnte Datei nicht finden.");
}

Image1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

}

So, what is the right way to handle this?

Thank you for any help!

Kind Regards!

Comment: and where is you "handling" code? you only show how you started an intent for result

Comment: There are thousands of Android device models. These come with tens, if not hundreds, of "default camera applications", as device manufacturers usually replace the AOSP one with their own. Beyond that, as Selvin indicates, please post the code where "nothing happens", as it is entirely possible that you are making some invalid assumptions in that code.

Comment: thank you for your comments. I've added the code

Comment: am i doing something wrong?